# Oracle runtime of comparing numbers versus comparing strings using a LIKE operator

Tags: oracle

My company database has 20 different string formats for their primary product label.  All 20 of them are stored in a separate look-up table

1 are strings starting with 'W'

2 are strings starting with 'TAIC'

3 are strings starting with 'D'

...

Next to the label attribute is the 'type' attribute, which stores the number related to which prefix the label contains.

I'm tasked with updating one of our modules for better runtime.  One of the queries I ran across deals with all labels containing 'TAIC' as the prefix.  However, instead of comparing whether the type number is equal to 2, it runs a LIKE operation checking for each label that begins with TAIC.

Now, my question is this -- since my goal is for better run time, would it be wise to switch from the like operator to just a regular equality operation against the type attribute?  It seems that running a regular expression-ish operation against a string would be a bit more time consuming, but enough to significantly alter the run time of a system?

Comment: Do you have existing indexes on the numeric column and/or the string column?

Comment: Both are primary keys, so both are indexed by default.

Comment: @ryebr3ad you can have only one primary key but that can contain multiple columns. The column order makes a HUGE difference! Can you tell the column order in the index? Does your SQL statement have any other WHERE conditions?

Comment: label is the primary key in the main table, while the numeric comparison is the primary key in the lookup table.  That being said, it's sort of indexed by default in the main table due to it being a foreign key.

Comment: Also, this statement is really the only where clause.  It's not a big statement, but it's one of only three statements used in the application.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the query and the explain plan output? Changing from varchar2 to number will make a measureable difference don't expect any jaw-dropping improvements. I have consistently had bad luck with selectivity estimates using LIKE operator, which led to poor choice of join order. When I worked around using LIKE the performance was improved, but not because LIKE was slow, but because the cbo picked the correct execution plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, both these operations:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   pk LIKE 'TAIC%'
```

and

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   type = 2
```

are sargable, that is able to use an index on the appropriate fields.

The numeric index, however, would be more compact and hence require less time to traverse, so using numeric comparison could increase the query performance.

Comment: Yeah, I figured indexes would make this a Catch-22 in itself.  But it's good to know a definite answer about this question.  Thanks.